# Ng-model with Cookie

Tags: javascript, angularjs, cookies, angular-ngmodel

I'm trying to take the first example from the angular.js homepage and adding in cookie support.

This is what I have so far: https://jsfiddle.net/y7dxa6n8/8/

It is:

```
<div ng-app="myApp">
  <div ng-controller="MyController as mc">
    <label>Name:</label>
    <input type="text" ng-model="mc.user" placeholder="Enter a name here">
    <hr>
    <h1>Hello {{mc.user}}!</h1>
  </div>
</div>

var myApp = angular.module('myApp', ['ngCookies']);

myApp.controller('MyController', [function($cookies) {

           this.getCookieValue = function () {
                   $cookies.put('user', this.user);
                   return $cookies.get('user');
            }

           this.user = this.getCookieValue();
}]);
```

But it's not working, ive been trying to learn angular.
Thanks

Comment: just typo in your code? myApp.controller('MyController', [function(`$cookie`) {  should be `$cookies` ?

Comment: I tried @TamaroTamaroidny it didnt work :( https://jsfiddle.net/y7dxa6n8/8/ i updated code above with this link and its contents

Answer (score 1):

I'd suggest you create a service as such in the app module:

```
app.service('shareDataService', ['$cookieStore', function ($cookieStore) {

var _setAppData = function (key, data) { //userId, userName) {
    $cookieStore.put(key, data);
};

var _getAppData = function (key) {
    var appData = $cookieStore.get(key);
    return appData;
};
return {
    setAppData: _setAppData,
    getAppData: _getAppData
};
}]);
```

Inject the shareDataService in the controller to set and get cookie value
as:

```
//set
var userData = { 'userId': $scope.userId, 'userName': $scope.userName };
shareDataService.setAppData('userData', userData);

//get
var sharedUserData = shareDataService.getAppData('userData');
$scope.userId = sharedUserData.userId;
$scope.userName = sharedUserData.userName;
```

Working Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/y7dxa6n8/10/

I have used the cookie service between two controllers. Fill out the text box to see how it gets utilized.

Comment: Thanks @Dev1 why do you recommend this way? I tried it, it didnt work: https://jsfiddle.net/y7dxa6n8/6/ can you please show me how to do it this way and also without this service way it will help my learning a lot.

Comment: The previous comment linked to me trying your method, and this is my simple method: https://jsfiddle.net/y7dxa6n8/8/ may you please help m get both working it will teach me a lot.

Answer (score 1):

ok, examined your code once again, and here is your answer
https://jsfiddle.net/wz3kgak3/

1. problem - wrong syntax: notice definition of controller, not using [] as second parameter
   If you are using [] in controller, you must use it this way:

   myApp.controller('MyController', ['$cookies', function($cookies) {
   ....
   }]);

this "long" format is javascript uglyfier safe, when param `$cookies` will become `a` or `b` or so, and will be inaccessible as `$cookies`, so you are telling that controller: "first parameter in my function is `cookies`

2. problem: you are using angular 1.3.x, there is no method PUT or GET in $cookies, that methods are avalaible only in angular 1.4+, so you need to use it old way:  `$cookies.user = 'something';` and getter: `var something = $cookies.user;`
3. problem - you are not storing that cookie value, model is updated, but cookie is not automatically binded, so use $watch for watching changes in `user` and store it:

   `$watch('user', function(newValue) {
       $cookies.user = newValues;
   });`

or do it via some event (click, submit or i dont know where)

EDIT: full working example with $scope
https://jsfiddle.net/mwcxv820/

Comment: Thaknks very much @Tamaro is it possible to use a getter/setter to make it work? Im trying it here: https://jsfiddle.net/wz3kgak3/1/ thanks for this help im learning a lot

Comment: $watch is method of $scope, so you must use `$scope` instead of `this`, also remove `ng-model="mc.user"`, just use `ng-model="user"`,  it was binding that value as `this.mc.user` in javascript (in angular, you can bind to non existing value / object, it will create it for you`, working example https://jsfiddle.net/mwcxv820/

Comment: Thanks @tam i have to run to bed now but will test thank you!